# How to get data from html to java in web application?

Tags: java, html, web-applications

I wanted to get data from html file and send it to java for MongoDb updates, how do I get data?

Comment: If you need HTML parsing, and extracting data from it, try [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the html page belongs to you can get data through ajax call or even through page submit.

But, if its third party page you need to do http get call to read content in java file.  Then get element by using "[jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)"  package.

**P.S.: Your question is still not clear to me. Please give the appropriate description so that I can help accordingly.**

Update

```
//In your html file
    <html>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    var myData = {"myId" : 123456};
    $.ajax({
            url: 'myServletName',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            success: function (data) {

            }

        });
    </script>
    </html>



    //In Java File (myServlet.java)


    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
                String jsonR = "";
                if (br != null) {
                    jsonR = br.readLine();
                }
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonR);
                Long myId = data.getLong("myId");
//You can use this variable (myId) for your further operations.
```

Comment: Basically I'm searching an id in MongoDb to change variables in database from Java, but to do that I need to get id from html and send it to Java. I can get the variable from Java to html with #{obj.xxx} is there a similar way for vice-versa?